# A question about Fourier multipliers

Tags: operator-theory, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

### The question

The question is 2.5.10 from [Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=94FxBQAAQBAJ&dq=grafakos%20fourier&source=gbs_navlinks_s&redir_esc=y). It starts by defining a multiplier

$$m_{\text{per}}(\omega)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}m(\omega -k),$$

where $m$ is a Fourier multiplier in the $\mathcal M_p$ space. It also holds that $m$ has support in $[0,1]^d$.

It is to be proven that $m_{\text{per}}$ belongs in $\mathcal M_p$ as well.

### Work so far

The multiplier $m_{\text{per}}$ is defined by the relation

$$T_{m_{\text{per}}}f(t)=\int\limits_{\mathbb R^d}m_{\text{per}}(\omega)\hat f(\omega)e^{2\pi i \langle\omega\mid t\rangle} d\omega.$$
We now go to the definition of $m_{\text{per}}$ to express the last integral as

$$\int\limits_{\mathbb R^d}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}m(\omega -k)\hat f(\omega)e^{2\pi i \langle\omega\mid t\rangle} d\omega\underbrace{=}_{(??)}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\int\limits_{\mathbb R^d}m(\omega -k)\hat f(\omega)e^{2\pi i \langle\omega\mid t\rangle} d\omega.$$

---

Here comes my **first question**: Is it possible to exchange that sum with the integral? I would hazard a guess that it is indeed possible so I continued while assuming it.

I think that a possible explanation would be Lebesgue's DCT or the fact that $m$ is compactly supported. Is that the case, or is it completely different?

---

Assuming the last equality is true we can make a change of variables $\omega\mapsto\omega+k$, and the differential doesn't change so we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\int\limits_{\mathbb R^d}m(\omega)\hat f(\omega +k)e^{2\pi i \langle\omega+k\mid t\rangle} d\omega&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}e^{2\pi i \langle k\mid t\rangle}\int\limits_{\mathbb R^d}m(\omega)(e^{-2\pi i \langle\cdot\mid k\rangle}f)^{\land}e^{2\pi i \langle\omega\mid t\rangle} d\omega\\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}e^{2\pi i \langle k\mid t\rangle}T_m(e^{-2\pi i \langle\cdot\mid k\rangle}f)(t)
\end{align*}

where the first equality is true after separating the exponential and also recalling the formula for a translation of the Fourier transform. The second one is the definition of the Fourier multiplier. We now take $L_p$-norm and use Minkowski's inequality as follows:

\begin{align*}
\|T_{m_{\text{per}}}f\|_{L^p}&\leq\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\|e^{2\pi i \langle k\mid \cdot\rangle}T_m(e^{-2\pi i \langle\cdot\mid k\rangle}f)\|_{L^p}\\
&\leq \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\|T_m(e^{-2\pi i \langle\cdot\mid k\rangle}f)\|_{L^p}\\
&\leq \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\|T_m\|_{L^p\to L^p}\|e^{-2\pi i \langle\cdot\mid k\rangle}f\|_{L^p}\\
&=\|T_m\|_{L^p\to L^p}\|f\|_{L^p}|\mathbb Z^d|.\ (??)
\end{align*}

---

I feel like I've taken many liberties, but talking about the inequalities, I've used the fact that the exponential function $e^{i\dots}$ has complex modulus 1. That is not a problem, but when we get to the last line, I think that it is wrong. That is because no term depends on $k$ and the sum is infinite and I also **haven't used the fact that $m$ is compactly supported**. At least not that I have noticed.

So, in concrete, my **second question** would be: Is my idea for this part correct? Except for the part where I have $\mathbb Z^d$'s measure. From here, how can I finish?

The only thing I need to prove is that $m_{\text{per}}$'s $\mathcal M_p$-norm is finite and that norm is the $L^p$ operator norm of $T_{m_{\text{per}}}$, so my strategy has been to find a bound with the $\mathcal M_p$ norm of $m$. I haven't been able to finish this up, so any hint, suggestion or answer is most welcome.